# Can I charge my iphone from my macbook pro (late 2013) without turning the laptop on?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, charge

I am trying to charge my phone using my laptop but that requires the laptop to be on. 
On my Lenovo, I can do that without turning the laptop on. 
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Macbook Pro USB port will supply power to devices if the Macbook is on or asleep. It will not do so if the Macbook is powered off, completely shutdown.

See here for more details on how the power is supplied, it can get tricky:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4049

Comment: This is true of all Apple laptops. Just shut the lid, same result as being powered off.

Comment: That's not what I had experienced. My phone doesn't get charged when I close the lid. Before the lid is closed, obviously enough, it was charged fine.

Comment: Some brief insight for this old thread - this is a design feature of Macbooks, one of several which allows the battery to last as long as it does, and one that many other manufacturers don't make. The issue is that the heat discharge is through the keyboard - when the lid is closed, it has no circulation, and immediately sleeps to prevent itself from overheating.

Comment: My macbook used to charge the iphone when I close its lid. Now it won't. Not sure if it's a hardware degrade or a software issue (running Yosemite now)

Comment: @cmason, if I use the mac mini or macbook pro to charge my iPhone, if iPhone will get harm?

Comment: @aircraft I can't imagine that Apple's computers would in any way harm Apple's mobile phones. I have charged all my iPhones over the years with my MacBook USB ports without issue.